# check_cv() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, model

i try to train a model but have a problem, this code works on other pc, but i have a problem.

my code

```
X = X_test
y = y_test
splitter = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)

X = X_test
y = y_test
splitter = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)
sel = SelectFromModel(
    PermutationImportance(
        model, 
        cv=splitter, 
        n_iter=3,
        refit=False,
        random_state=random_seed
    ),
    threshold=0.05,
).fit(X, y)
```

My error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1729559/1137452974.py in <module>
      2 y = y_test
      3 splitter = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)
----> 4 sel = SelectFromModel(
      5     PermutationImportance(
      6         model,
```

...

```
check_cv() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I think the problem is that "kfold" gives 3 arguments (n_splits=5, random_state=47, shuffle=True)
but "CV" requires 2

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the lines where you use `check_cv` ?

Comment: kfold is my "CV". Gracias